# Suggestions for New Sites?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I didn't see a place to put this on Stack Exchange, so how does one go about suggesting a new site associated with Stack Exchange? For instance, CatOverflow would be amazing IMO.

Comment: Just a note that a proposal for "Cat Overflow" will likely be closed since [pets.se] already exists.

Comment: Cats are no pets. They make their owner think  they are, but that's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what the Area51 site is for.  Check it out.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/